# Phone authentication using cloud firestore in ios swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-datastore

[image: firebase database image here]

[image: phone authentication login user image here]

[image: firebase database user phone number repeated with same user uid image here]

In my app i am using phone authentication for login and storing user logged in user phone number and uid in database. when login with existing user phone number,  it creates new document id with same uid and phone number you can look out the image 1 and 3.

Here is the code i used to login and if user exist mean it should check and navigate to home controller else sign user detail controller.

```
     @IBAction func loginbtn(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let credential: PhoneAuthCredential = PhoneAuthProvider.provider().credential(withVerificationID: defaults.string(forKey: "authVID")!,
                                                                                  verificationCode: otpText.text!)
    Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential)
    {
        (user, error) in
        if error != nil
        {
            print("error: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
        }
        else if user != nil
        {


            print("Phone number: \(String(describing: user?.phoneNumber))")
            let userInfo = user?.providerData[0]
            print("Provider ID: \(String(describing: userInfo?.providerID))")

            let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
            var ref: DocumentReference? = nil


            ref = self.db.collection("Users").addDocument(data: [
                                    "phoneNumber"   : user?.phoneNumber as Any,
                                    "UID"           : user?.uid as Any

                                ]) { err in
                                    if let err = err {

                                        print("Error adding document: \(err)")

                                    } else {

                                        print("Document added with ID: \(ref!.documentID)")

                                    }
                                }

            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController")
            self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)


        } else {




            }


        }

    }
```

can anyone help me out of this, i am nearly struggling with past one day!!!

Comment: You are calling the method "addDocument" which, as you are seeing, created a new document assigning an auto generated document id: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document   you would need to use the user's uid as the document id along with the set or update method: collection('Users').document(<UID>).set()

Comment: @Gerardo Very sorry for delay response. Thanks for the answer!! Can you add it has a answer so that i can give upvote. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also go with the firebase generated UID. 
You already have that line, but haven't used it:

```
let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
```

So try to replace `"UID": user?.uid as Any` with `"UID": currentUser as Any`

Answer (score 4):

You are calling the function "add" which creates a new document assigning an auto generated ID as mentioned [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document). 
Instead you'd need to be calling the function "set" using the user's uid as key, like follows:

```
db.collection("users").doc(uid).set...
```